# Jersey multiple POST methods with same path

Tags: post, jersey, jax-rs

I am trying to make two types of POST methods, both of which create objects and populate a database.

Method 1 adds a single object to the database.

Method 2 adds an array of objects to the database.

```
// Create new agent status
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createAgentStatus(@Context HttpServletRequest request, AgentStatus agentStatus) {
    ...
}


// Create multiple agent statuses at once
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createAgentStatuses(@Context HttpServletRequest request, Collection<AgentStatus> agentStatuses) {
    ...
}
```

I am getting an error, as expected, because Jersey cannot tell the difference between the two paths. Both POSTS are treated the same to Jersey, so it cannot tell which one to route which to based on my input.

How can I make it so that Jersey can detect the format of my input and route accordingly? Thank you

Ex:

Method 1 JSON input (createAgentStatus) :

```
{
    "agentId":"A123456",
    "agentStatus":"NOTREADY",
    "timeStamp":"2015-10-08T13:37:32:235Z",
    "reason":"Break",
    "reasonCode":"100"
}
```

Method 2 JSON input (createAgentStatuses) :

```
[
    {
    "agentId":"A123456",
    "agentStatus":"NOTREADY",
    "timeStamp":"2015-10-08T13:37:32:235Z",
    "reason":"Break",
    "reasonCode":"100"
    },
    {
    "agentId":"B654321",
    "agentStatus":"AVAIL",
    "timeStamp":"2015-10-08T13:37:32:235Z",
    "reason":"Call",
    "reasonCode":"200"
    }
]
```

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution? I am struggling with the same problem and I think jaxrs just doesn't allow such configs.

Comment: @mdzh you have to do two separate api mappings. In the above, I did .../agents for a single agent post, and .../agents/batch for an array input post

Comment: Nope, I was hoping to achieve that using a single api mapping. If possible, I wish to avoid using query params and separate paths.
The JAX-RS specification http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/jsr339-jaxrs-2.0-final-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1508483467_e4b9fad161269c317886c27b1e8802e5
- section 3.7.2 (3) (c) specifies that "If
after sorting, there is more than one maximum element in M, implementations SHOULD report
a warning and select one of these methods in an implementation dependent manner." -> which means that support for this use case is not official

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could use a @QueryParam to determine which option the endpoint needs and call the appropiate method, something like "batch=true" or you could have a path "/batch" to insert multiple records.

Comment: The `@QueryParam` solution would basically be the same as using two different paths, which is, according to the question, not desired.

Comment: Not quite true, you are basically helping the endpoint decide whenever it needs to make a single or batch insertion. The `@QueryParam` can even have a `@DefaultValue` so it just has to be sent on batch requests. The path is always the same.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I don't think this is a bad solution. But it basically requires a change in the specs or possible client implementations, at least for batch requests. Today, I thought a lot about possible solutions that would not require such changes. Nothing working came to my mind, but I still think a complete solution should cover this.

Answer (score 0):

I think a single endpoint is enough to achieve this. If we pass in a list of objects it should create objects based on the size of the list.

In the backend, you can traverse through the list to add the objects to the database. A single object gets created if the request list has only one object and multiple gets created if it has multiple objects.